# How to measure/rate the effect of a exogenous covariate in a ARIMAX Model?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, model-evaluation

I have an ARIMA model, I'm trying to figure out how much an external variable (exogenous covariate) could improve the forecast, so I need to "synthesize" a rate that tell me the usefulness (or impact) of a new external regressor.
Does anyone know a good way to do it?

Comment: Here is one way https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124533/transfer-function-in-forecasting-models-interpretation/125108#125108