# python statsmodels extract equation ARIMAX

Tags: python, arima, statsmodels

This is a model summary with two exogenous variables and AR of lag order 2, how to extract the equation out of this like Y= coff1* L1+ ....

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Multiply your AR(2) polynomial by each of your input series polynomials . It is straight forward in this case but it can get complicated if you have moving average structure in your error term or dynamic structure in one or more of your exogenous input AND if you have a constant in your model.

I don't know if your software has this feature (extract pure right-hand side equation) but I have seen it elsewhere.

https://autobox.com/pdfs/SARMAX.pdf presents the general single output equation

EDITED after OP'S comment to shed light:

See my answer here [Transfer function in forecasting models - interpretation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124533/transfer-function-in-forecasting-models-interpretation/148719#148719) which provides more details on converting the estimated transfer function model/COEFFICIENTS to a pure/expanded REGRESSION model ... pure right-hand side model without any error terms by employing additional lag terms for Y and each of the X's.

Comment: If X1 and X2 are exog variables and L1 is lag term. Plus, x1,x2,l1 are coefficient for X1,X2 and L1 respectively. Then the equation should be y=const+ x1*X1+ x2*X2+ l1*L2 Kindly shed light on this.