Coupled Multivariate Regression and AR(1) Process for the Covariates
I am wondering how to fit the following model:
I have a standard multivariate regression, and a set of covariates X. I want to couple my regression equation with an AR(1) process for the dynamics of the covariates, that is, rather than estimating y given the covariates, I want to estimate first the covariate from the AR(1) dynamics, and then given the estimated covariate estimate y via multivariate regression. This is basically a flavor of a state space model, but there are no latent variables, we have two time series, Y for the dependent variables, X for the covariates, with the extra layer that the covariates follow some dynamics.
How can I fit such a model?
The model looks like this:

​

Hi ksheen: I hate to keep throwing questions back at you but do you happen to mean that $\epsilon_t$ is AR(1) ( obviously, rather than $X_t$ ) because, in that case, you are correct that you wouldn't need a state space representation. But, if you really do mean that $X_t$ is AR(1), then I need to think about that case. I think it needs a state space representation but I want to see if I'm missing something.

ksheen: I've been looking at the equations you provided and I don't see how that is not the standard KF ?  For simplicity's sake, let's assume that everything is a scalar. Then, the state is $X_t$ which happens to have AR(1) dynamics. The AR(1) dynamics are represented by the state equation for $X_t$. Then, for the observation equation, $Y_t$ is a linear function of the state plus an error term. So, I could be not understanding something but I think this is standard KF ? ( harvey, harrison and west etc )

That is exactly my question, would a Kalman filter apply in this case? my understanding is that KF is for when you have unobserved states, but here we have the observed dataset X

Oh, I didn't realize that $X_t$ was an actual data set. I think ( but not sure ), that you may want to use a transfer function approach. Let me see if I can find anything useful on that and get back to you. If I tried to explain it, I wouldn't do it justice.

Unfortunately, this was all I could find as far as applying transfer function modelling to time series. https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/288816444.pdf  Most of my time series books are in storage and transfer function modelling tends to fall under control engineering. I'm pretty sure that the Box and Jenkins text covers it. Between Box and Jenkins text and the paper I linked to, hopefully you can make some progress on seeing if it's appropriate.   Or others, may know if there is some other approach that is appropriate here.

ksheen: I thought about this some more and am going to write out a method that I should work and be valid ) as an answer. Hopefully you can, then, go about it the way I explain it. Stay tuned !!!!

ksheen: After I wrote my answer out, I realized that it wasn't going to work so I deleted it.  I then looked for a decent explanation of transfer function modelling. I found control engineering explanations that weren't helpful or time series papers that looked useful but were not freely available. The best thing I found was this: I hope it helps some. I didn't have time to go through it carefully but it got a good review by the person who asked the question. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/124533/transfer-function-in-forecasting-models-interpretation

ksheen: this problem was continuing to bother me because the use of transfer functions seems like an over-complication to a pretty straightforward model. ( An AR(1), then a regression where the AR(1) is the independent variable in the regression ). Eventually, I found this which seems to cover your problem exactly. The problem is that I'm not used to viewing the KF the way he is. So, I have to go through it more carefully with the hope of understanding it. He also uses terms like "state model" and "data model" which I have never seen before. Still, it should help a lot once understood.

This essentially says that you're problem can be put in KF framework. I think he is viewing $\phi$ as the state possibly but I have to go over previous lectures because current lecture tends to depend on previous. https://web.stanford.edu/class/stats253/lectures_2014/lect5notes.pdf
